# Answer with explanation and patch removed from response

Tags: discussion

Last week I came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766666/1183444) that helped me out immensely. Since the time of that post, the base code has changed making the "patch" within the answer a little difficult to apply, so I created my own patch and contributed it to the list of answers. Since I'm new to StackOverflow, I couldn't respond inline with the other answer. Therefore I posted a new answer below, referencing the previous answer, some context, and a link to the patch. However, user [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) removed my answer. I [reached out to him](https://twitter.com/onlybluefeet/status/469547355394424832) to determine the reason, but he simply asked me to post my question here. Could someone please assist in this matter? Thank you.

Comment: A plain link to a customized patch of yours (even it originated in another answer) is likely not useful to other users without some amount of explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The answer was flagged by another user as being a link-only answer. In general, the community frowns on answers that consist of little more than a link to an external site. These links have a tendency to go away after a while, leaving dead-ends here. We've been instructed to remove ["see my tutorial"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) kinds of link-based answers.

However, something like a patch is difficult to express without a link. In your case though, your answer really wasn't a standalone answer but was an expression of another answer. As you don't have the reputation to leave it as a comment, I've converted it to a comment on the appropriate answer. That way, it can add to the value of the original answer yet not be too much of a problem if and when the link goes away at some point in the future.

Comment: Thank you for both moving my question to the correct location (I thought I had place it on meta.*, but obviously not), and moving my comment. I definitely appreciate it.